# How can i create a partial class at runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic-compilation

How can i create a partial class at runtime?

Example: I have a class

```
public partial class A
{

}
```

I want to create partial of my A class at runtime from an XML file.
because I don't compile my project when any change in code.
I know this is little meaning less but i need this.

XOML files work for me?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question please?  Are you trying to compile code at runtime?

Comment: This question sounds like you have a misunderstanding of what a partial class is.  If you explain a bit about what you're trying to do, you may get answers that can explain a bit more about how to solve the issue.

Comment: Even after the edit, I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point of partial classes is to be able to define parts of it in different source files. In the end, after compilation, what you have is a regular class, indistinguishable of any other. So there is not such a thing as "instantiating a partial class".

Answer (score 7):

The `partial` keyword is used to separate a class across multiple code files. The compiler merges them together into a single class.

[MSDN: Partial Class Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

A partial class doesn't exist in the CLR. It's more of a Visual Vtudio trick than anything else.